# How to improve NOT EXISTS performance in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, not-exists, sql-tuning

```
INSERT INTO table3
SELECT
  tbl1.pk_1, tbl1.pk_2, tbl2.pk_3, tbl1.pk4
FROM
  table1 tbl1, table2 tbl2
WHERE
  tbl1.pk_1 = 'root' and
  NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM table3 tbl3
     WHERE tbl3.pk_1 = tbl1.pk_1 and tbl3.pk_2 = tbl1.pk_2 and tbl3.pk_3 = tbl2.pk_3 and tbl3.pk_4 = tbl1.pk_4) 
;
```

My SQL statements looks like this. table1 and table3 have over 1000000 rows,table2 has 100 rows. This SQL statement is very slow. It takes more than 100 seconds finish. Is there any way to improve it?

Comment: Better to go for MERGE statement.

Comment: Can you show what indexes and constraints you have on all three tables?

Comment: Also, is your cross-join between `tbl1` and `tbl2` intentional? I feel there's a missing join predicate...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to insert data into table3. These data is selected by join table1 and table2. Some of the join results already exists in table3, so I need to use NOT EXISTS to remove these results.

Comment: I assume either `table3` or `tbl3` is a typo. Probably should be corrected just for clarity.

Comment: Thanks but it is not a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Use MERGE, it serves faster

```
merge into table3 tbl3
using (select tbl1.pk_1, tbl1.pk_2, tbl2.pk_3, tbl1.pk4
         from table1 tbl1, table2 tbl2
        where tbl1.pk_1 = 'root') tb1
   on (tbl3.pk_1 = tbl.pk_1 and tbl3.pk_2 = tbl.pk_2 and tbl3.pk_3 = tbl.pk_3 and tbl.pk_4 = tbl1.pk_4) 
when not matched then 
     insert (tbl3.pk_1, tbl3.pk_2, tbl3.pk_3, tbl3.pk_4)
     VALUES (tbl.pk_1, tbl.pk_2, tbl.pk_3, tbl.pk_4);
```

Comment: I tested MERGE.On my server, it is actually twice slower.

Comment: Is there any index on table3? If not, try after creating composite index on (pk_1, pk_2, pk_3, pk_4).

Comment: Yes, pk_1,pk_2,pk_3,pk_4 is the composite index

Answer (score 1):

I found it is very hard to improve the performance for this SQL statements. I test MERGE, however it takes more than 200 seconds. Even if the performance can be improved, I guess it can only be improved like 1 or 2 seconds, Which doesn't meet our business requirement. (I have around 20 SQL statements like this one).
So I reviewed our business logic, and I found that this SQL statement is not necessary. We just need a more careful algorithm to gather the new data, Make an cartesian product then insert this new data into table3. In this way, this SQL statement can be removed.And the new process only takes a few seconds!
I think when we improve a SQL statement, please first make sure this SQL statement is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your table expression is incomplete:

```
FROM
  table1 tbl1, table2 tbl2
```

You're (probably accidentally) producing a cartesian product between table1 and table2, with 1000000 x 100 records in memory. Your table expression should probably read:

```
FROM
  table1 tbl1, table2 tbl2
WHERE
  tbl1.some_column = tbl2.some_column
```

Or even better (to prevent such things in the future)

```
FROM
  table1 tbl1
JOIN
  table2 tbl2 ON tbl1.some_column = tbl2.some_column
```

Comment: table1 and table2 are independent. Our application requires to do a cartesian product between table1 and table2. I think the bottleneck is "NOT EXISTS" which requires a "NESTED LOOPS ANTI" search. I'm wondering it there any to do "NOT EXISTS" better.

Comment: OK, I understand. So how many records do you expect per update? I.e. will the `NOT EXISTS` predicate remove most of the tuples produced from the cartesian product again?

Comment: Yes exactly. Although the  cartesian product millions of rows, only a few rows (around 100 ) will pass the "NOT EXISTS" condition.

Comment: Then I agree that `MERGE` might outperform this `INSERT .. SELECT`.

Comment: Thanks very much. On my server, MERGE works slower than INSERT .. SELECT. I found a way to bypass the "NOT EXISTS" part. It's related to our business logic so developers never think in this direction before. Now I can remove this SQL statement. Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: @user2878435: No problem. You can then answer your own question on Stack Overflow. This would be quite helpful to future visitors.